# wrapper div for widgets not showing with all widgets

Tags: widgets

I have registered a Widget area with the following code:

```
// Register Sidebars
function custom_sidebars() {

    $args = array(
        'id'            => 'footer_sidebar',
        'class'         => 'footer_sidebar',
        'name'          => __( 'Footer 3 foto ruimte', 'text_domain' ),
        'description'   => __( 'Widget ruimte voor 3 1 foto plaatje widgets', 'text_domain' ),
        'before_widget' => '<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 singleWidgetBlock">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>'
    );
    register_sidebar( $args );

}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'custom_sidebars' );
```

The before_widget and after_widget is working as expected with all widgets but one. With one widget the wrapping div doesn't show up at all.

I can't find anything in the widget code itself that would prevent this.

Has anyone else run into this problem? Or does anyone know of something that would override the before_widget and after_widget code in a widgetized area? My Google Fu is seriously lacking this time.

For completeness also the code of the widget itself below.

```
/**
 * Register the Widget
 */
add_action( 'widgets_init', create_function( '', 'register_widget("fcc_single_image_widget");' ) );

class fcc_single_image_widget extends WP_Widget
{
    /**
     * Constructor
     **/
    public function __construct()
    {
        $widget_ops = array(
            'classname' => 'fcc_single_image_widget',
            'description' => 'Widget that uses the built in Media library.'
        );

        parent::__construct( 'fcc_single_image_widget', 'FCC Single Image Widget', $widget_ops );

        add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'upload_scripts'));
    }

    /**
     * Upload the Javascripts for the media uploader
     */
    public function upload_scripts()
    {
        wp_enqueue_script('media-upload');
        wp_enqueue_script('thickbox');
        wp_enqueue_script('single_image_widget', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'upload-media.js', array('jquery'));

        wp_enqueue_style('thickbox');
    }

    /**
     * Outputs the HTML for this widget.
     *
     * @param array  An array of standard parameters for widgets in this theme
     * @param array  An array of settings for this widget instance
     * @return void Echoes it's output
     **/
    public function widget( $args, $instance )
    {
        // Add any html to output the image in the $instance array

        ?>
        <h6 class="widget-title"><?php echo $instance['title']?></h6>
        <img class="img-responsive" id="sidewidgetTopImage" src="<?php echo $instance['image']; ?>">
        <?php
    }

    /**
     * Deals with the settings when they are saved by the admin. Here is
     * where any validation should be dealt with.
     *
     * @param array  An array of new settings as submitted by the admin
     * @param array  An array of the previous settings
     * @return array The validated and (if necessary) amended settings
     **/
    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {

        // update logic goes here
        $updated_instance = $new_instance;
        return $updated_instance;
    }

    /**
     * Displays the form for this widget on the Widgets page of the WP Admin area.
     *
     * @param array  An array of the current settings for this widget
     * @return void
     **/
    public function form( $instance )
    {
        $title = __('Widget Image');
        if(isset($instance['title']))
        {
            $title = $instance['title'];
        }

        $image = '';
        if(isset($instance['image']))
        {
            $image = $instance['image'];
        }
        ?>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:' ); ?></label>
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>" />
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'image' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Image:' ); ?></label>
            <input name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'image' ); ?>" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'image' ); ?>" class="widefat" type="text" size="36"  value="<?php echo esc_url( $image ); ?>" />
            <input class="upload_image_button" type="button" value="Upload Image" />
        </p>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Is it just the wrapping `div` that doesn't show or the whole widget content?

Comment: Just the wrapper div. The widget itself shows fine. Weird thing is, if I put in any other widget thee wrapper div does show as intended.

Comment: You're not echoing the wrapping divs. The `register_sidebar` only defines the `div`, but doesn't render it. You need to extract the texts and echo them.

Comment: Yes that was it! I was barking up the wrong tree. Instead of looking for reasons it didn't display for this widget I should have been looking for reasons why it would display for this widget. Thanks! For after me who run into the same problem I wrapped the content of the widget function in echo $args['before_widget']; and echo $args['after_widget'];

Comment: Glad that helped. Could you accept the answer please? So your question doesn't show up later as still needing attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not echoing the wrapping divs. The register_sidebar only defines the div, but doesn't render it. You need to extract the texts and echo them, like this:

```
public function widget( $args, $instance ) {    

    extract( $args );

    $title         = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] );

    echo $before_widget;

    if ( $title ) {
        echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;
    }

    ... do widgetty things ...

    echo $after_widget;

}
```